# Combine/merge an unknown number of observables together as they are created

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

What I would like to do is:

- Call a function (`DoWork`) which as part of it's work will subscribe to multiple hot inputs through multiple `Worker` classes
- Before calling the function subscribe to all the updates that `DoWork` subscribes to
- Once finished, dispose of all the subscriptions
- It is probable that at least one incoming event will fire before `DoWork` has completed.

Questions:

- Are `Subject`s the correct way to do this? It feels like there should be a better way?
- How to ensure that once the subscription in `Main` is disposed, all of the `incomingX` subscriptions are also disposed - i.e. `Main` should control the lifecycle of all the subscriptions.

  ```
  void Main()
  {
      var worker = new Worker();
      using (worker.UpdateEvents.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine()))
      {
          worker.DoWork();
      }
  }

  public class Worker1
  {
      private readonly Subject<string> updateEvents = new Subject<string>();

      public IObservable<string> UpdateEvents { get { return updateEvents; } }

      public void DoWork()
      {
          // Do some work
          // subscribe to a hot observable (events coming in over the network)
          incoming1.Subscribe(updateEvents);

          var worker2 = new Worker2();
          worker2.UpdateEvents.Subscribe(updateEvents);
          worker2.DoWork();
      }
  }

  public class Worker2
  {
      private readonly Subject<string> updateEvents = new Subject<string>();

      public IObservable<string> UpdateEvents { get { return updateEvents; } }

      public void DoWork()
      {
          // Do some work
          // subscribe to some more events
          incoming2.Subscribe(updateEvents);

          var workerN = new WorkerN();
          workerN.UpdateEvents.Subscribe(updateEvents);
          workerN.DoWork();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It's tricky to understand what's needed here, could you perhaps distill your example further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

James's answer (use `Subject` and `Merge`) captures the essence of the question.  This answer offers a pattern that I've found useful in this situation (based on your comments to James's answer).

Essentially the pattern is to have your worker's expose an `IObservable` that the caller will subscribe to before calling `DoWork`.  But this sort of API (call A before calling B) is problematic because it introduces temporal coupling.

To eliminate the temporal coupling, you end up *turning your worker itself into an cold Observable* that implicitly calls `DoWork` when the caller subscribes.  Once you realize the power of cold observables and the ability to use `Observable.Create` to take action when an observer subscribes, the sky's the limit on the Rx chains you can create without ever needing to reach for a `Subject`.  Here's an example based on your original code.

`Worker` is simple.  It just subscribes to `incoming1` and to `Worker2`.
`Worker2` is slightly more complex.  It subscribes to `incoming2`, performs some additional work, then finally subscribes to `WorkerN`.

All the while maintaining the correct `OnError`, `OnCompleted` logic which your original code example fails to do.  Meaning that the observable stream that `Main` sees does not `Complete` until **all** of the incoming streams and work streams complete.  But `Main` fails as soon as any of the incoming streams or work streams fails.  Your code example with multiple calls to `Subscribe(someSubject)` would cause the `Subject` to complete (and thus Main's incoming stream to complete) as soon as any of the `incoming` streams completes.

```
public class Worker1
{
    public IObservable<string> UpdateEvents { get; private set; };

    public Worker1()
    {
        // Each time someone subscribes, create a new worker2 and subscribe to the hot events as well as whatever worker2 produces.
        UpdateEvents = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            var worker2 = new Worker2();
            return incoming1.Merge(worker2.UpdateEvents).Subscribe(observer);
        });
    }
}

public class Worker2
{
    public IObservable<string> UpdateEvents { get; private set; };

    public Worker2()
    {
        // Each time someone subscribes, create a new worker and subscribe to the hot events as well as whatever worker2 produces.
        UpdateEvents = Observable.Create(observer =>
        {
            // maybe this version needs to do some stuff after it has subscribed to incoming2 but before it subscribes to workerN:
            var doWorkThenSubscribeToWorker = Observable.Create(o =>
            {
                DoWork(o);
                var worker = new WorkerN();
                return worker.UpdateEvents.Subscribe(o);
            }

            return incoming2.Merge(doWorkThenSubscribeToWorker).Subscribe(observer);
        });
    }

    private void DoWork(IObserver<string> observer)
    {
        // do some work
        observer.OnNext("result of work");
    }
}


void Main()
{
    var worker = new Worker();
    worker.UpdateEvents.Do(x => Console.WriteLine()).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although James's solution works this feels much more in the RX spirit.

Comment: Note that this solution is predicated on having all workers available at the point of subscription... I wasn't sure I could make that assumption given the title and so used a root subject for dynamic adds - nothing out of the Rx spirit there I assure you!  However, very glad this works for you! Nice idea Brandon. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow exactly what you are asking for - a [small but complete program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) would help here I think.

That said, there's nothing wrong with using a `Subject` to introduce input into the Rx pipeline - there's a lot written about that on StackOverflow and elsewhere, so I won't rehash it.

Going just by the title of your question, I wonder does the following suit your purpose?

#### Combining a dynamic number of streams

To do this you can use `Merge` on a stream of streams. Your streams must all be of the same type - if they are not, you can create a suitable container type and project them into that type using `Select`. For simplicity, I will assume the unified type is `long`.

To start create a container for the streams:

```
var container = new Subject<IObservable<long>>();
```

Then combine the contained streams:

```
var combined = container.Merge();
```

Subscribe to combined to consume the results in the usual way, and dispose the subscription to unsubscribe from all streams at once.

You can then add streams as they are created like this:

```
// assume we got this from somewhere - e.g. a "worker" factory function
// Observable.Create may well be helpful to create an observable
// that initiates getting data from a network connection upon its subscription
IObservable<long> someNewStream;

// add the someNewStream to the container (it will be subscribed to once added)
container.OnNext(someNewStream);
```

#### Example use

```
// dump out the combined results to the console,
// IRL you would subscribe to this to process the results
var subscription = combined.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

// add a stream of longs
container.OnNext(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));    
Console.WriteLine("Stream 1 added");
Console.ReadLine();

// add another stream
container.OnNext(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));    
Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
Console.ReadLine();

// this will unsubscribe from all the live streams
subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: Yes, I had wondered if `Merge()` was the way to go and this would do exactly what I want. One specific thing I wasn't sure about though is - if I create a `Subject` in `Main` is it okay to pass it around through all the workers? I am sure I read that as Subject's are stateful, sharing them wasn't a good idea. Thread safety for example.

Comment: You should encapsulate this as an implementation detail of a component responsible for aggregating the workers. I envisaged each worker returning an observable that would be consumed by the aggregator. Workers would have no knowledge of being aggregated.

Comment: It's hard to be more specific without more detail of your scenario.